# ahk run pid is not same as shown in Window Spy

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to capture PID from Run command and use the PID to resize window. But no luck. After spending several hours I realized that PID shown in message box different from PID inspected via Spy Window. Any suggestion?

```
Run, "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe",,, PID
;Sleep, 300
MsgBox, %PID% is the process PID ; --> PID shown here is different from PID inspected via Window Spy
WinWait, ahk_pid %PID%
;Sleep, 300
;WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
WinMinimize, ahk_pid %PID%
;WinMove, ahk_pid %PID%, ,500, 250, 200, 100
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the window that appears, doesn't come from the `git-bash.exe` process.
It comes from `mintty.exe`, which gets launched somewhere down the line after you run `git-bash.exe`.

Most simple thing you can do, is wait for the window to appear after launching `git-bash.exe`, like so:

```cpp
Run, % "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
;// sleep a bit because other things from mintty.exe seem to get lauched first as well
Sleep, 1000
WinWait, % "ahk_exe mintty.exe"
;// get the hwnd of the last found window (the window we waited for above)
hwnd := WinExist()

;// and if you for some reason really need the PID, you can do e.g this to get it
WinGet, pid, PID, % "ahk_id " hwnd
MsgBox, % pid
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it worked. Actually initially I was trying with chrome window (finally I need to align chrome) but my code was not working. Then I found an example of internet that was git-bash.exe. I thought let me first test the code with git-bash and if it work then I will translate to google chrome. I manged to fix the code but this strange issue (git-bash.exe) made me spend  hours. I just tried chrome.exe in earlier code and it worked. :)